# What is the View Hierachy and how can I add a MpVolumeView to it?

Tags: ios, xcode, mpvolumeview

I'm attempting to add a mpvolumeview to my app to allow to select an output channel, however I'm struggling to understand the documentation.

By view Hierachy, I'm assuming that this is just this, where I've set the class to MpVolumeView, however it is not appearing.

The link is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

This is the paragraph that I can't quite understand:

"Use this class by embedding an instance of it in your view hierarchy. The following code snippet assumes you’ve placed an instance of the UIView class on a view using Interface Builder, sizing and positioning it as desired to contain the volume view. Point to the UIView instance with an outlet variable—named, in the case of this example, mpVolumeViewParentView. You’d typically place code like that shown in Listing 1 in your viewDidLoad method."

Screenshots:
[image]

I think I need the volumeView in the View class of my Main.storyboard
[image]

Code that I'm then using to add the volumeView :

```
//  ViewController.swift


 Import UIKit
 import AVFoundation
 import MediaPlayer
 //import SwiftUI


 let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)

 let myView = UIView(frame: rect)


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

//let wrapperView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 200, width: 300, height: 20))

var recordingSession:AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
var numberOfRecords:Int = 0
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet weak var buttonLabel: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableview: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var airPlayView: UIView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: myView.bounds)
    myView.addSubview(volumeView)
```

I am developing on IOS 9.3.5 on Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Please add code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, read be screen readers, searched, etc

Comment: Sorry yeah - am using a vm and wasn't playing ball, now added cheers

Comment: `myView` doesn't appear to be a part of your view hierarchy at all, so its `MPVolumeView` definitely won't appear. Are you trying to add `MPVolumeView` via interface builder or in code?

Comment: Either tbh - I was following the tutorial that I linked which refers to this `parentView` so I attempted the same thing, but didn't know in that example what the parentview was. I cannot drag views to my main controller, so assumed adding a new one to the Voicify folder on the left was what they meant, then change that class to MPVolumeView.

Comment: Assuming `ViewController` is actually being used in your code (which I'm not clear on for sure), you can add `MPVolumeView` directly to the view hierarchy like this in `viewDidLoad`: `self.view.addSubview(volumeView)`

Comment: That added it but to the top left of the screen for some reason - any idea how I can move this to say the middle of the screen?

Comment: "for some reason" -- because you defined the frame as `(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)`. Search for "autolayout" and "constraints" to learn how to place views in Swift. There are multiple approaches and you can experiment to find one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot man - hopefully with this now I can use AirPlay stuff